# MYSQL ERROR 1017 - Can't find file: 'staff' (errorno: 2)

Tags: mysql, database

need help i get the above mentioned error when trying to open or query my table , how to fix this error please.

Tried repair it fails with below error

'mysql> repair table dw.staff;'

```
`+--------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+'

`| Table  | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text     `                     |'
' +--------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+'
'| dw.axe | repair | Error    | Can't find file: 'staff' (errno: 2) |'
'| dw.axe | repair | status   | Operation failed                  |'
'+--------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+'
```

`

Comment: `errno: 2` == no such file. Check does the table body file exists (file is not deleted/renamed) in the filesystem and has correct access rights. If true then try drop and re-import its tablespace.

Comment: How to drop and re-import its tablespace please

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-tablespace.html

Comment: Drop and Recreate fixed it